# Missing static content in Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo

I have searched far and wide and tried multiple solutions found on the odoo forums (primarily).

We had an an otherwise perfectly working odoo installation, the only bad thing was that it was lacking resources; we had given it too little RAM. So, naturally, the operations guy goes and turns off the virtual servers, changes the xen configuration file for that virtual server, and gives it more memory. He then starts it back up.

After having done that, all static content is gone. The logs show long rows of 404 on static content. We've tried reloading the module list and we've tried `DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE datas_fname SIMILAR TO '%.(js|css)';`. Those are the solutions we could find, but haven't worked for us.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know which is the filestore path, the config entry is `data_dir`? If you delete all attachment records you have lost all the references to those files, and that is not a good idea

Comment: @ChesuCR `data_dir` in `/etc/odoo-server.conf`  is `/odoo/.local/share/Odoo`

Comment: Then, there has to be a folder with your database name inside that folder where all files are stored. There is a field in the `ir_attachment` model called `store_fname` with the specific file locations

Comment: That's how the attachments work. Anyway if you show a complete error I may help you with the statis content. Sometimes this issue happens when the system parameter `web.url` is badly assigned